# Python, XML and MySQL - ascii v utf8 encoding issues

Tags: python, mysql, xml, encoding, utf-8

I have a MySQL table, with XML content stored in a longtext field, encoded as utf8mb4_general_ci

Database Table
[image]
I want to use a Python script to read in the XML data from the transcript field, modify an element, and then write the value back to the database.

When I try to get the XML content into an Element using `ElementTree.tostring` I get the following encoding error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "ImageProcessing.py", line 33, 
   in <module> root = etree.fromstring(row[1])
File  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etre‌​e/ElementTree.py", line 1300, 
   in XML parser.feed(text)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etre‌​ e/ElementTree.py", line 1640, 
   in feed self._parser.Parse(data, 0) 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 9568: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Code:

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

# Creates the config parameters, connects
# to the database and creates a cursor 
config = {
  'user': 'username',
  'password': 'password',
  'host': '127.0.0.1',
  'database': 'dbname',
  'raise_on_warnings': True,
  'use_unicode': True,
  'charset': 'utf8',
}
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# Structures the SQL query
query = ("SELECT * FROM transcription")

# Executes the query and fetches the first row
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()

while row is not None:
    print(row[0])

    #Some of the things I have tried to resolve the encoding issue
    #parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
    #root = etree.fromstring(row[1], parser=parser)
    #row[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    #Line where the encoding error is being thrown
    root = etree.fromstring(row[1])

    for img in root.iter('img'):
        refno = img.text
        img.attrib['href']='http://www.link.com/images.jsp?doc=' + refno
        print img.tag, img.attrib, img.text

    row = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Please provide full stack trace of error

Comment: Seamus, we're at risk of increasing the scope of the original question. You should create a new question for the new problem, and upvote and accept my question if you think it fixed the original problem.

Comment: I've uploaded a new question now, I'll update this to revert back to the original scope

Comment: Fantastic - I'm looking into the em-dash problem as we speak

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Hi Alastair, did you have any luck with this? No probs if you didn't have time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got everything well setup and your database connection is returning Unicodes, which is a good thing.

Unfortunately, ElementTree's `fromstring()` requires a byte str not a Unicode. This is so ElementTree can decode it using the encoding defined in the XML header.

You need to use this instead:

```
utf_8_xml = row[1].encode("utf-8")
root = etree.fromstring(utf_8_xml)
```